# C Coding: For loop/call by reference confusion

Tags: c

In this program, I don't quite understand what's going on below the comment: /*pass the array */. The output of this program should be 31 iterations of    Enter temperature #0,#1,#2.....#30 and then convert those user entered values into Celsius. My confusion is in what purpose or how the function call convert(temps) works and how everything below that functions as a whole.

Any clarification on how the code 'works' to achieve said output would be great. In addition is the call by referencing happening at the convert function, if so could somebody please explain the dynamics within there.

Thank You.

```
#define COUNT 31
void convert (float heat[]);
void main()
{
    float temps[COUNT];
    int index;
    /*load the array with values*/
    for (index = 0; index < COUNT ; index++)
    {
        printf("Enter temperature #%d: ", index);
        scanf("%f", &temps[index]);
    }
    /*pass the array */
    convert(temps);
    for (index = 0; index < COUNT ; index++)
        printf("%6.2f\n", temps[index]);
}

/*******************convert function ************************/
void convert (float heat[])
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < COUNT; index++)
    {
        heat[index] = (5.0/9.0)*(heat[index]-32);
    }
}
```

Comment: the function `convert` modifies the array : it is because the array isn't copied, only its address (pointer) is passed to the function

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, it becomes a pointer (so this is clear, I prefer to declare functions using pointer syntax: `void convert(float *heat)`). Passing by reference (by pointer in C) means the function can modify the actual argument passed to the function, while passing by value means that the function works on a local copy of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The function *convert* receives a pointer to the first element of the *temps* array and then modifies its elements. In other words, the array is never copied. Since only a pointer is passed there is no way to tell how long the formal parameter *heat* is inside *convert*. It is therefor a good idea to pass the length of the array as well. Here is how I would do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))

void convert(float heat[], int heatLen)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < heatLen; i++) {
        heat[i] = (5.0 / 9.0) * (heat[i] - 32);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    float temps[31];
    int i, nRead;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(temps) ; i++) {
        printf("Enter temperature #%d: ", i);
        nRead = scanf("%f", &temps[i]);
        if (nRead != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    convert(temps, LEN(temps));

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(temps) ; i++) {
        printf("%6.2f\n", temps[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing as `call by reference` in C. The language **only** support call by value.

The call

```
convert(temps);
```

passes a **value**. Since `temps` is an array it really passes the `address of the first element in the array`. For the function it looks like a `pointer to float` - we say that the array decays into a pointer when used as a function argument.

Inside the `convert` function you can then change the value of the elements in the array by using the passed address value (aka by using the pointer). This can be done be simple indexing, like

```
temps[i] = .....;
```

or

```
*(temps + i) = ....;
```